# Ansible gives me an error during execution of some playbooks

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

I use Ansible 2.9.2 on Ubuntu Server 18.04 + Python 3.6.9. Here is a simple Ansible project: https://github.com/770715/ansible.git

If I run:

`ansible-playbook -i aws_ec2.yml add-ssh-keys.yml`

it works just fine but when I try to run:

```
ansible-playbook -i aws_ec2.yml playbook.yml
```

I get an error:

```sh
dev@ops:~/code/build/ansible$ ansible-playbook -i aws_ec2.yml playbook.yml
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/__init__.py:80: RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (1.25.7) or chardet (3.0.4) doesn't match a supported version!
  RequestsDependencyWarning)
ERROR! unexpected parameter type in action: <class 'bool'>

The error appears to be in '/home/dev/code/build/ansible/roles/docker/tasks/main.yml': line 1, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:


- name: Install Docker
  ^ here
```

The YAML file syntax seems to be correct (I have checked that with a number of different validators).

urllib3 (1.25.7) and chardet (3.0.4) are in the latest versions. I'd appreciate it if you could help.

Comment: Do not include external links in your question, expecially when they may become broken links !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The format of your role is incorrect.  While a *playbook* specifies target hosts and other material, a *role* is simply a list of tasks. You're getting the error because you've formatted `roles/docker/tasks/main.yml` like a playbook.  Instead of:

```
- name: Install Docker
  gather_facts: No
  hosts: docker

  tasks:
    - name: Install yum utils
      yum:
        name: yum-utils
        state: latest
[...]
```

You should have:

```
- name: Install yum utils
  yum:
    name: yum-utils
    state: latest
[...]
```